# onChange event for custom select menu jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

The .change menu I'm using for a jQuery Mobile custom select menu is not triggering at all. I'm attempting to append the jQuery Mobile select menu dynamically:

**Appending jQuery Mobile Select Menu**

```
      $('#visSelectionMenu').append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="visMenu" class="select">Select Visualization:</label><select name="visMenu" id="visMenu" data-native-menu="false" class="visualizationMenu">');

      var visualizationList = ['Triangle','Square'];

      for (var i = 0; i < visualizationList.length; i++) {
        $('#visMenu').append('<option value=\'' + visualizationList[i] + '\'>' + visualizationList[i] + '</option>');
      }

      $('#visMenu').selectmenu();
       $("#visMenu").selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

**OnChange Method**

```
$("#visMenu").change(function () {
  console.log("hello");
    var $this = $(this),
        val   = $this.val();
    alert('onChange = ' + val);
});
```

Comment: u just forgot to put semicolon isntead of coma  $this = $(this); on change method

Comment: I get the same problem and it seems to be caused by the data-native=false property. All other jQueryMobile selectmenus work fine with the change event.